# Pushing non dynamically allocated objects to a vector of pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I've been trying to figure out this issue while I was coding on Codeblocks but didn't have any luck.

So basically I have the following code inside a function:

```
Node * newNode;
newNode->data = num;
//root is defined somwhere at the top as 'Node * root';
root->adj.push_back(newNode);
```

and the following struct:

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    vector<Node*> adj;
};
```

When I do the push_back to the vector the program just cycles for 2-3 seconds and exits with a non-zero exit code. If I allocate the memory dynamically It seems to work correctly. Does the program somehow blow up when the pointer is not pointing to a specific block of memory?

Comment: Undefined Behavior.  Does `newNode` point to a valid `Node` object?  Where does it point?  Consider [turning on compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/bT6fP8vev) to avoid problems like these.

Comment: `newNode->data = num;`  you can not access `data` if `newNode` has not been initialized.

Comment: Maybe `Node * newNode = new Node(); ` could solve the issue

Comment: and write a constructor for `Node`. It should be `Node * newNode = new Node(num);`.

Comment: Side-note: You probably want to use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (ideally via `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared`) rather than raw pointers here and let C++ handle the work; since you clearly don't understand why `new` is necessary, odds are you aren't `delete`ing either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Traversing" pointers that are not pointing at objects is undefined behavior in C++.

The pointer doesn't have to point at a dynamically allocated object, but that is typical.  The pointer could point at an automatic storage object.  For example:

```
Node bob;
Node* root = &bob;
```

however, in every case, you are responsible for managing lifetime of these objects.  Automatic storage objects survive until the end of the current scope, temporary objects until the end of the current full expression, and dynamically allocated objects until they are `delete`d.

Smart pointers can help a bit with lifetime management issues, but they only help.  They do not solve it, and you still have to be aware of lifetime.

Many post-C++ languages have automatic garbage collection that makes lifetime less of the programmers problem.  You do not have this help in C++.